# Force auto adjust of monitor from software under Linux

Tags: linux, xrandr

with a analog monitor I'm always getting image that is shifted to the right when the Xorg starts. Is there a way to force auto-adjusting from software for example by using xranrd?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can use XRandR tool. For example if your second monitor is connected via VGA cable you can use the command:

```
 xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1
```

**--auto** parameter will try to set resolution automatically.

If you want specific resolution you can experiment with --mode parameter, for example

```
 xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x1050 --right-of LVDS1
```

For more details see the post here:

http://devmain.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/dual-monitors-configuration-for-linux.html